# extracting multiple strings from a line

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following json (only a longer version with hundreds of ids) and it is a one line document:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"templateid":"10001"},{"templateid":"10047"},{"templateid":"10050"}],"id":2}
```

I want to extract the ids and write them into a file so that it would look like this:

```
10001
10047
10050
```

Couldn't figure this out myself. Appreciate any help.
This is CentOS by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq -r '.result[].templateid' input.json
```

It's a very good tool. Please download the binary, `chmod +x jq`, read the [manual](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `jq '.result[].templateid | tonumber'`